# How to prove that an ideal can not be generated by 2 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

In Kunz's "*Introduction to commutative algebra and algebraic geometry*", page 137-139, particular monomial affine curves are described. Here is the [link](https://books.google.it/books?id=4jsbXKkfpsEC&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=introduction+to+commutative+algebra+and+algebraic+geometry+kunz&source=bl&ots=QuBnFD7Mr0&sig=eFr-J1NkqmyR_acGCC_oGGAW8ag&hl=it&sa=X&ei=8Ww2Va_DF4ngaMrogLAJ&ved=0CGsQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20commutative%20algebra%20and%20algebraic%20geometry%20kunz&f=false).

> In case the curve is not an ideal theoretic complete intersection, how can I prove that the ideal of curve is not generated by 2 elements?

Kunz suggests to consider the ideal $I$ modulo $(X_1^{c_1},X_2^{c_2},X_3^{c_3})$, but I can not develop this argument. Thank you for your help.